# How to prevent embedded Javascript from autoscrolling a page

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

Is there any way to prevent embedded javascript from auto-scrolling a webpage?

We have a calendar application embedded into multiple pages on our Squarespace site via javascript. Recently, it developed a bug that has been causing every page it's embedded on to automatically scroll to the embedded block.

They say they're working on it, but it's been weeks now and I need to either remove their scripts until they fix them or, if I can, prevent the script from auto-scrolling in the first place.

Our website is https://www.kutenaiarttherapy.com. Here is an example of the code that they provided and we embedded:

```
<p class="loxi" data-background-color="" data-categories="8" data-color="#24c9b8" data-default-layout="list" data-font-family="Roboto" data-is-demo="false" data-show-category-filter="0" data-show-location-address="0" data-show-location-filter="0" data-show-search-filter="0" data-show-view-switcher="0" data-show-list-view-image="1" data-show-social-media-buttons="1" data-site-id="7169" data-subdomain="kati" data-theme="dark" data-timezone="America/Vancouver" data-title="KATI Events" data-venue="all"><a href="https://kati.loxi.io">View more events</a> on <a href="https://loxi.io">Loxi.io</a></p><script async src="https://kati.loxi.io/embed/client.js"></script>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: So, I'm a little to busy to write something up, but there is one way you could hack this. You could put a div position fixed to the top of your web page and keep the display none and give that div the class name `loxi` which I assume is what the JS uses to place it. Then after waiting for it to load (choose your method) use javascript to move the loaded div contents to where you want them on the page. This will sort of trick that anchor so it will scroll to the top of the page, which is where the user already is.

Comment: The other thing you could do is write javascript that listens for scroll and just stops it, essentially making the page unscrollable and then after a certain amount of time, kill that listener. Neither is very pretty, but it's better than having your home page scroll to the bottom like its currently doing.

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceJohnson! I understand that you're busy. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about javascript, really, and so don't know where to go from here.::blush::  Maybe when you have time you could give me a code snippet to paste in? Or someone else could? Thanks for your help, folks!